# How would I correct the program so it runs correctly?

Tags: java

This program should have a  “while” loop that asks repeatedly for a number until a number   divisible by 6 or 17 is  given. When that occurs, the program should     display the total number of numbers read that are not divisible by 6 or 17.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DivisibleBy6or17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Value : ");
        int nbr = kbd.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while ((nbr % 7 ==0 ) && (nbr % 16 == 0)){

            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
            nbr = kbd.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers read : " + count);


    }

}
```

Comment: does it show any error?>

Comment: noit just doesnt output what it should

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
  while (!((nbr % 7 ==0 ) && (nbr % 16 == 0))){
```

You want to do while it is False

Comment: hmmm i tried that and the input of 9474 should be numbers read: 0, but it continues to ask to enter a value and does not cut off the loop

Answer (score 0):

Condition is wrong, it should be an or operand on the while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DivisibleBy6or17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Value : ");
        int nbr = kbd.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        while (!((nbr % 17 == 0 ) || (nbr % 6 == 0))){

          count++;
          System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
          nbr = kbd.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers read : " + count);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using or (||) instead of and (&&)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while ((nbr % 7 ==0 ) && (nbr % 16 == 0)){

            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
            nbr = kbd.nextInt();
        }
```

To

```
 /* while nbr **isn't** divisible by 7 or 16 */
 while (! ((nbr % 7 == 0 ) || (nbr % 16 == 0)) ){

                count++;
                System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                nbr = kbd.nextInt();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Not sure whether the numbers are right, you question mentions numbers different to the code. I've used the ones in the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivisibleBy6or17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        int count = 0;

        //loop forever
        while ( true ) {

            //prompt
            System.out.print("Enter Value : ");         
            int nbr = kbd.nextInt();

            //if number is divisible 
            if ( nbr % 7 == 0 || nbr % 16 == 0 ) {
                 //leave loop
                 break;             
            } else {
                //add to count
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers read : " + count);
    }
}
```